# Java sorted double-linked list: How to insert a new node quickly in the right position?

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list, binary-search, doubly-linked-list

I have a double-linked list that needs to have fast inserts and removes. I can just transverse the whole thing in either direction to find where to insert or remove, but **is there a more clever way to find the insertion or removal point**? First thing that came to mind was binary search, but since it is a linked list with no indexes (not an array), I am not sure how to jump around my linked list.

What is the right approach here to make insertions and removals the fastest they can be?

Comment: You have picked the wrong data-structure. Linked lists have _O(n)_ lookups.

Comment: @rocketboy Perhaps I need to use it in conjunction with another datastructure to make this faster?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The smart way is to move towards a [Skip List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list).

Other approaches include cacheing recent accesses and making intelligent guesses where to start your search, at the end, at the start or at a recent spot.

Comment: Actually I think even in a Skip List, accessing elements is fast, but the time required for insertion and removal increases slightly because you need to update more number of links. Ofcourse the +ves seem to outweigh the -ves.

Comment: Exactly... so if you want fast inserts -> use an array

Comment: @AbhishekBansal - There is indeed a trade-off between speed of locating the correct insert point and speed of insert. There is also an increased memory cost. This is why programming is a craft, not a science.

Comment: @GerritCap Array!??? Noooo you are forgetting about shifting. This list is SORTED!

Comment: @GerritCap - Sorry but using an array only makes finding faster because you can binary-chop - it slows down inserting because you often need to copy the array to make space for inserts. A skip-list is a balance between the two.

Comment: If you manage your array like ArrayList does by allocating a large array and memorizing how much entries are in it and use System.arrayCopy it is extremely fast in shifting !

Comment: @GerritCap - depends on the length of your list. A 100,000 entry list would crawl on insert if implemented as an array but a skip-list would scale well.

Comment: The question was clear: find fast the correct insertion point, it means insert between the 3rd and 4th element. Either your are talking about a lineair structure like a list -> behind every smart data structure there will be an array, our use something like a Binary tree, but then it is not a list anymore

Comment: A skip list is a very good way to do this. Find, insert, and removal are O(log n). For even moderately sized lists (a few thousand items--perhaps even a few hundred), skip list will outperform array for speed of insertion and removal. Note that the standard skip list isn't double-linked, so if you need the ability to go backwards through the list you'll have to add another pointer to the node. Skip list uses an *average* of two pointers per node. If you need the back pointer, then it'll be three pointers per node (again, on average).

Answer (score 0):

You may use a [B-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) instead of the double linked list or, as mentioned in an other answer, use a [Skip_list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list). For fast searching a double linked list is the wrong data-structure.

Comment: Problem is that I also need fast transversal. Fast removal and fast insertion. Can't have everything, I understand, but trying to do something smart to make my linked list faster.

Comment: @JohnPristine: see no problem in it. Traverse a `Skip_list` is as fast as traversal of a double-linked-List. That can also be achieved for a `B-tree`.

Answer (score -1):

As you indicate yourself, because the linked list is not indexable there is no way than to loop over the list to find the right insertion point...

Comment: Come on. There must be a smart way of solving this problem. Perhaps by using a secondary data-structure.

Comment: @JohnPristine Every datastructure has it's advantages and disadvantages. If there was one datastructure that would be good for every problem, there would be no use for other datastructures. Unfortunately, that is not the case.